# NET Core: bindings redirect equivalent

Tags: asp.net-core, plugins, assembly-binding-redirect

I've got a web app which loads dlls dynamically from a db. Even though the assemblies are restricted to a few libraries (ex.: Dapper), there's still the problem of dll hell. For instance, if the main site is using dapper 1.50.7 (strong name version) and one of the assemblies is using 1.50.5, then assembly ends up generating an io exception saying that it can't find version 1.50.5.

I've done a couple of searches and haven't found any definitive answer. For instance, this [post](http://blog.rytmis.net/2016/03/29/asp-net-core-and-assembly-binding-redirects/) says that you can still use app.config, but it's still not working.

So, any advice on how to solve this? Is there really no way to solve this kind of issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, handling the `Resolving` event of the default `AssemblyLoadContext` instance so that it returns the latest loaded assembly was enough for me.